# Can redundant variables be removes in transition to Chomsky normal form grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have the following context-free grammar:
$$
S\to aAb|aaBb|ab\\
A\to S|B\\
B\to C|S\\
C\to aC
$$
and I need to convert the grammar to Chomsky normal form (CNF).

After removing unit rules I get:
$$
S\to aAb|aaBb|ab\\
A\to aAb|aaBb|ab|aC\\
B\to aAb|aaBb|ab|aC\\
C\to aC
$$

Before I convert the grammar to CNF, I think the production rule $C\to aC$ is redundant because $A$ or $B$ already lead to $aC$ so can I delete the rule $C\to aC$?

Also the rule $A$ is identical to the rule $B$. Can either of them be removed as well?

This would the result of the $2$ improvements above (not yet CNF):
$$
S\to aAb|aaBb|ab\\
A\to aAb|aaBb|ab|aC\\
$$

Comment: Can someone answer this?